# Animation like default Transition animation.

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, winrt-xaml

WinRT control's default Transition are simply superb and i would like to make transitions like the same form my WPF controls. How could i step forward.

Any guidelines?

Comment: I suggest picking a single transition you are looking to emulate, such as Item pop-in/out, then work on that and ask questions along the way. "How do I make this happen automatically for each item that is added or removed?", "How do I make it pop in from the right instead of the left?", etc.

Comment: Here is one. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/197132/Simple-WPF-Page-Transitions